# What is apiclient in Android?

Tags: android, sms

```
private void requestHint() {
HintRequest hintRequest = new HintRequest.Builder()
       .setPhoneNumberIdentifierSupported(true)
       .build();

PendingIntent intent = Auth.CredentialsApi.getHintPickerIntent(
        apiClient, hintRequest);
startIntentSenderForResult(intent.getIntentSender(),
        RESOLVE_HINT, null, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

What is apiClient in the above code? I am trying to do sms verification in Android. Where will i get apiClient?

Answer (score 1):

apiClient is `GoogleApiClient` object use to access the Google APIs provided in the Google Play services library (such as Google Sign-In, Games, and Drive). You can create the object like following

```
GoogleApiClient apiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getContext())
           .addApi(Auth.CREDENTIALS_API).enableAutoManage(getActivity(), GoogleApiHelper
           .getSafeAutoManageId(), new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                     @Override
                     public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
                         Log.e(TAG, "Client connection failed: " + connectionResult.getErrorMessage());
                     }
         }).build();
```

Comment: what is `GoogleApiHelper` and is there any dependency for that?